# The default is 50% if you pass a 24-bit color: 0x0000ff (50% opacity, blue)

Tags: hex, google-maps-static-api

[Rendering polygon with Google Static Maps API URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147503/rendering-polygon-with-google-static-maps-api-url)

> The default is 50% if you pass a 24-bit color: 0x0000ff (50% opacity,
>   blue)

and to make that 100% he shows:

> 0% opacity: path=color:0x0000ff00

Straight from that link. My question is *simple*: How do I make any 24bit color 100% transparent? Like what if I had #898989? or #E20FE8? Or some other random color?

Answer (score 1):

As said in the answer, and in the documentation that it links to.

> When a 32-bit hex value is specified, the last two characters specify the 8-bit alpha transparency value. This value varies between 00 (completely transparent) and FF (completely opaque). Note that transparencies are supported in paths, though they are not supported for markers. (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#PathStyles)

The last byte (two hex digits) indicates transparency in 1/255ths. When not given, it defaults to 50%.

So to set a color to 100% opacity, add `FF` at the end.